# Can ThreadLocal be used as Key in HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, thread-local

Can ThreadLocal be used as Key in HashMap?

If so, how does it work and is it generally a bad idea? What should I look out for and be aware of?

Comment: It sounds like a really bad idea. `ThreadLocal` instance is not meant to be used that way and a lot depends on its `equals` method which potentially could give different results depending on which thread called it. Why don't you just use the value that `ThreadLocal` is holding?

Comment: This question is weird. On one hand, that is a bizarre idea. On the other hand, it is so bizarre that I actually started wondering about it. Unofrtunately, that is not the kind of question that should be asked here. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: After having a quick look, I see that `ThreadLocal` doesn't implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods. So it won't work.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I've actually tried it, this works just fine

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak It would work, in the same way as an `IdentityHashMap`. The question is whether it has any meaning. OP should provide a use case.

Comment: @RealSkeptic It's just a hypothetical question, I don't have any specific use case or need to use TL as a key. Just wondering

Comment: *"What should I look out for and be aware of?"* - Axe murderers who get annoyed by bizarre hypothetical questions :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ThreadLocal` as a HashMap key like any other object. Whether it has any meaning is a different topic.

Basically you can have problems if you use a mutable object as a key for things like `HashMap`, `HashSet` and so on, because those classes usually use `hashCode()` (hence the name) to put stuff in buckets and retrieve it. So if you use a mutable object as a key, then change the object (in a way the hashCode changes) and then try to retrieve the entry by key, you will not find the entry anymore as the map will look in the wrong bucket for the entry.

In the case of `ThreadLocal` this would not be a problem, as it does not override `equals()` and `hashCode()` and thus the `hashCode()` will not change if you change the object, so you *could* safely use the `ThreadLocal` as key.

Answer (score 1):

As Jaroslaw Pawlak commented, since `ThreadLocal` doesn't implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` it is not suitable for the **key** in `HashMap`, at least if you expect it to be well behaved.

Even if it did, it would be useless. Considering the use-case of `ThreadLocal`, it would be far clearer to use the contained object as the key.

Having a map with one `ThreadLocal` (with thread specific contents) mapping just ends up with having the internal map of `ThreadLocal` (the one that maps the thread to the value) being used for the actual mappings.

Not to mention that `ThreadLocal` instances are somewhat recommended against. The common use cases they have are solved by introducing "native" threadlocal classes, such as `java.util.concurrent.ThreadSafeRandom`.

Comment: What is wrong with the behavior of an object that doesn't override `hashCode` and `equals`? It's merely an identity-based hash map. It's perfectly behaved if you use the same object.

Comment: @RealSkeptic exactly, so I'd say this answer is wrong. :-)

Comment: Because if you want `IdentityHashMap`, you should explicitly use it. Using a regular `HashMap` with an additional `ThreadLocal` weirdery is just unclear programming.

Comment: But that's a different issue. It may be weird, but it's well defined and predictable. And one can argue that you only need `IdentityHashMap` if you have a value-based key where you *don't* want to use its natural value.

Comment: Considering this question is based on neither need or requirement, I'd say this is primarily opinion based. It's also recommended to use *immutable* objects as keys, so the proposed solutions aren't optimal in any way.

Comment: @Kayaman immutability with regards to `Hash*` classes is defined by `equals`/`hashCode`. As `ThreadLocal` does not override those, it is immutable for this context and thus usable pretty fine as key. Noone said that only `ThreadLocal` is used as key in that map, so you can have other entries with other keys in the same Map that override `equals`/`hashCode`. Using an `IdentityHashMap` would yield a pretty different behavior. Regarding the question of OP, your answer is plainly wrong. It may be a bad decision to do it or not, that depends on the use-case. The question was whether it will work!

Comment: @Vampire The question had no basis. Based on that (or rather the lack of it), I say "just because you could, doesn't mean you should".

Comment: But the question was not whether someone should, that would actually be "primarily opinion-based". The question was whether you could and that is a legal question which has "sure, of course" as answer. ;-)